# What's the Italian for 'rep-whore'?

Tags: word-choice

[Rep whore:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rep%20whore)

> - A person who is obsessed with their status on an internet forum so bribes/ does favours for members of that forum in an attempt to achieve higher rep points. I on the other hand am simply a whore and proud of it.

This is a common (and derogatory) definition for the kind of Internet user described above. Is there an  appropriate Italian term that covers that definition?

Comment: As usual, it's hard to prove the non-existence of something, but, as far as I know, no, there is no Italian term for a _rep whore_ (no hyphen, AFAIK)

Comment: I agree with @Walter Tross. Italian often borrows from English as far as computer and Internet-related terms go. Especially for such very context-specific terms, I doubt there are direct translations. We would rely on periphrases.

Comment: I actually kind of disagree on the fact that this is a common term.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi - The folowing question aroused my curiosity about a possible Italian version of the expression..it does seem quite popular though: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/whats-a-less-offensive-substitute-for-rep-whores

Comment: @Josh61 I mean it's not common in the sense that it's a niche term. You probably won't ever hear it outside SE or similar places. That brings the chances of it being translated close to 0.